# how to output a specific array in PHP?

Tags: php, api

I try to code a output from a API.

So I took this at first:

```
$api_response = json_decode(file_get_contents("--LINK TO API--"));
```

if I var_dump the $api_response, a code like

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(2) "ok"
  ["count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["data"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (4) {
      ["clan_id"]=>
      int(1000001876)
      ["nickname"]=>
      string(10) "JakenVeina"
      ["id"]=>
      int(1001147659)
      ["account_id"]=>
      int(1001147659)
    }
  }
}
```

So if I want to output for example only the account_id, I tried more ways:

```
$account_id = $api_response["data"]["account_id];
echo $account_id;
```

and

```
echo $api_response->account_id;
```

Nothing worked for me.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Don't know if it's a typo here or in your code but you are missing one " at the end of `$account_id = $api_response["data"]["account_id];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youre not asking `json_decode` to decode to an array.

you need (note the true):

```
$api_response = json_decode(file_get_contents("--LINK TO API--"), true);
```

then you should be able to access the array keys as needed.

Also `account_id` is one child level lower than you're specifying.

Comment: Thanks. It work, but I have one Question left. It only works if i put [0] in the account_id variable. What is this using for?
See: $account_id = $api_response['data'][0]['account_id'];
//EDIT Got it, thanks :)

Comment: because `['data']` is an array of arrays

Answer (score 0):

The first level of your result is a `stdclass` therefore you have to use `->` to get the `data` array. data then is an array and you access its members using `[]`.

To get your account_id you can use:

```
$account_id = $api_response->data['account_id'];
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an object array so you need to access it like an object, for a numeric value, you need to use `{}` otherwise you can't access it.

```
$api_response->data->{0}->account_id; //1001147659
```

Also you can did the same thing using the `true` in the `json_decode` as a second parameter. If you did this in there your array would be converted as associative array and you can access it like:

```
$api_response['data'][0]['account_id']; //1001147659
```

Both will produces same result.

Comment: Who give the `downvote`??? Who did this thing?? Please tell me why.